# Copy data from multiple sheets into 1 based on criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I have a document that has multiple sheets, I need to search column A using an inputstring to find all values that match them copy them to the MergedData sheet. It needs to excluding "SUB PAYMENT FORM", "Details" and "MergeData" from the search. It needs to search each sheet starting at row 16 working down til last row.

In the merged data sheet i need the data to start being copied at Cell A1, followed by A2 and so on...

I would like for when the button has been click and data copied i would like to have a message box display, stating the sheet names where data has been copied from, i would also like it to display the sheets name of where no data was found.

Below is the code that i have at the moment, it searches all the relevant sheets and copys the data to the MergedData sheet. But it does not give me the message boxes stating where data was found or not.

It also pasted the data in the MergedData sheet starting in row 2 rather that row 1.

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Aarron

```
Sub SearchForString() 
Dim FirstAddress As String,  
WhatFor A String 
Dim Cell As Range, Sheet As Worksheet     

With Application    
    .ScreenUpdating = False         
    .EnableEvents = False        
    .CutCopyMode = False     
End With   

WhatFor = InputBox("What are you looking for?", "Search Criteria")
Worksheets("MergedData").Cells.Clear

If WhatFor = Empty Then Exit Sub 
For Each Sheet In Sheets
If Sheet.Name <> "SUB PAYMENT" And Sheet.Name <> "MergedData" And Sheet.Name <> "Details" Then

With Sheet.Columns(1) Set Cell = .Find(   WhatFor, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

If Not Cell Is Nothing Then 
FirstAddress = Cell.Address 
Do
Cell.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("MergedData").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
Set Cell = .FindNext(Cell)
Loop Until Cell Is Nothing Or Cell.Address = FirstAddress
End If 
End With 
End If
Next Sheet Set Cell = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: _It also pasted the data in the MergedData sheet starting in row 2 rather that row 1._  Did you trie `Cell.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("MergedData").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0)` ?

Comment: @Trimax Hi mate, yes i tried that, but it doesn't copy all data, it only copies the first line from the first sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the habit to increment your code properly to improve readability.

This should work properly :

```
Sub SearchForString()

Dim FirstAddress As String, _
    WhatFor As String, _
    Cell As Range, _
    Sheet As Worksheet, _
    MatchIn As String, _
    NotMatch As String

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .CutCopyMode = False
End With

WhatFor = InputBox("What are you looking for?", "Search Criteria")
Worksheets("MergedData").Cells.Clear

If IsEmpty(WhatFor) Then Exit Sub

For Each Sheet In Sheets
    If Sheet.Name <> "SUB PAYMENT" And Sheet.Name <> "MergedData" And Sheet.Name <> "Details" Then
        With Sheet.Columns(1)
            Set Cell = .Find(What:=WhatFor, _
                            After:=.Cells(16, 1), _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                            MatchCase:=False, _
                            SearchFormat:=False)
            If Not Cell Is Nothing Then
                FirstAddress = Cell.Address
                'MsgBox Cell.Parent.Name
                If InStr(1, MatchIn, Cell.Parent.Name) <> 0 Then
                    'already noted sheet
                Else
                    MatchIn = MatchIn & Cell.Parent.Name & Chr(13)
                End If
                Do
                    Cell.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("MergedData").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                    Set Cell = .FindNext(Cell)
                Loop Until Cell Is Nothing Or Cell.Address = FirstAddress Or Cell.Row < 16
            End If
        End With
    End If
Next Sheet

Set Cell = Nothing
Worksheets("MergedData").Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete

For Each Sheet In Sheets
    If Sheet.Name <> "SUB PAYMENT" And _
            Sheet.Name <> "MergedData" And _
            Sheet.Name <> "Details" And _
            InStr(1, MatchIn, Sheet.Name) = 0 Then
        NotMatch = NotMatch & Sheet.Name & Chr(13)
    End If
Next Sheet

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .CutCopyMode = True
End With


MsgBox WhatFor & " found in :" & Chr(13) & MatchIn & _
        Chr(13) & "Not found in :" & Chr(13) & NotMatch

End Sub
```

Comment: can i be cheeky and ask you to have a look at two of my other questions, please. 1) SUMIF, and Copy columns to another workbook, based on criteria. THANK YOU :)

Comment: If you can upvote this, It would be sweet! ;)
I'm taking a look to the other questions too